# What is this Swift ternary operator? A == B ? C : D

Tags: swift, legacy-code

I inherited an iOS app that is crashing at this line (unexpected nil). What is your best interpretation of what is going on here?

```
indexPath.row.number == selectedItem ? cell.deselectStyle() : cell.dedeselectStyle()
```

The `cell.deselectStyle()` and `cell.dedeselectStyle()` functions don't return anything. I can't seem to find any information on what is going on here. `selectedItem` is a `NSNumber!`.

Comment: `selectedItem` is nil that's why it is crashing

Comment: I get that, I'm just wondering what is the point of everything after the `?`.

Comment: `if (indexPath.row.number == selectedItem){cell.deselectStyle()} else{cell.dedeselectStyle()}` It doesn't matter if they return something. It's not `if (selectedItem){indexPath.row.number = cell.deselectStyle()} else{indexPath.row.number = cell.dedeselectStyle()}` as you seem to misderstand

Comment: If the condition is true, this one `cell.deselectStyle()` is called. If it is false this `cell.dedeselectStyle()` is called.

Comment: Oh, ok, I see it now.

Comment: I edited the question as I found it misleading. C and D are different in your question example.

Comment: Check this https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID71

Answer (score 0):

Probably The reason the crash is that `selectedItem` is `nil`; I think you misunderstand the difference between the `?` for *optionals* and the `?` for implementing the ternary operator.

The ternary operator has nothing to do with -implicitly- checking if the value is nil, you might need to implement a `guard` statement or `if let` (optional binding) before the step of doing the ternary operator comparison.

It should be similar to:

```
if let selectedItem = selectedItem {
    indexPath.row.number == selectedItem ? cell.deselectStyle() : cell.dedeselectStyle()
} else {
    print("selectedItem is nil!")
}
```

Or, if an early return required:

```
guard let selectedItem = selectedItem else {
    print("selectedItem is nil!")
    return
}

indexPath.row.number == selectedItem ? cell.deselectStyle() : cell.dedeselectStyle()
```

---

To make it more clear to you, check the following code snippet:

```
let nilValue: String! = nil

if nilValue == "test" { }
// fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

// OR
let isValueTest: Bool = (nilValue == "test") ? true : false
// fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

That's why you should unwrap the value before accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

NSNumber could be `nil` leading to a crash if you try to access it. Add a `guard` to check that is not `nil`.

```
guard let s = selectedItem?.intValue else {
    cell.dedeselectStyle
    return
}

indexPath.row == s ? cell.deselectStyle() : cell.dedeselectStyle()
```

I've assumed it's safe to assume the cell is not selected if the NSNumber is `nil`, however you should really check the logic in your code to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

This is a conditional statement. Think of it like an `if` statement:

```
if indexPath.row.number == selectedItem {
    cell.deselectStyle()
} else {
    cell.dedeselectStyle()
}
```

If the condition is true, the code between `?` and `:` will be executed. If not, the code after the `:` will be called. You should know that the `?` has nothing to do with Optionals.

In your case, `selectedItem` seems to be `nil`. Therefore, you need to either only execute the code if `selectedItem` is not `nil`, you could use an `if let` statement:

```
if let selectedItem = selectedItem {
    indexPath.row.number == selectedItem ? cell.deselectStyle() : cell.dedeselectStyle()
}
```

Or, you could insert a default value that will be used instead of `selectedItem` if it is `nil`:

```
indexPath.row.number == (selectedItem ?? false) ? cell.deselectStyle() : cell.dedeselectStyle()
```

The code above will use either the value of `selectedItem`, or `false`, if `selectedItem` is `nil`. You can leave out the parentheses, I just put them there for better visualization.

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

to better understand it, play in your Playground

```
func f0() -> Int { print(0); return 0 }
func f1() -> Int { print(1); return 1 }
func fa() -> String { print("a"); return "a" }

[true, false, true, true].forEach {
    $0 ? f0() : f1() // warning: expression of type 'Int' is unused
}

[true, false, true, true].forEach {
   _ = $0 ? f0() : f1() // OK
}

[true, false, true, true].forEach {
    $0 ? f0() : fa() // error: result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types 'Int' and 'String'
}

[true, false, true, true].forEach {
    _ = $0 ? ( 1 == f0()) : ( "A" == fa()) // OK
}
```